# Determinant of a square matrix with a particular pattern

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let  $A=[a_{ij}]$ be the square  matrix of  order $n$ whose entries are given as follows. For $1\le i,j\le n$ we have $$a_{ij}=
                                         \begin{cases}
                                          ij,&\text{if $i=j$}\\
                                          ij+1,&\text{if $i\neq j$}
                                          \end {cases}$$
 Evaluate the determinant  of  $A$.

I took an arbitrary $3\times 3$ and then an arbitrary $4\times 4$ matrix to see  what things go like. Well  the matrices do have an interesting pattern **:**

**They look like a sequence of $L_i$ and $L_i'$ joined at right angle with decreasing lenghts  where  $L_i$ is *the $i$-th row without $i-1$  elements*  and $L_i'$ is *the $i$-th coloumn  without $i-1$ elements*.**

But  the  requirement  is  to find the determinant . May be the pattern could contribute to that , I guessed. PLease   give  me  some  clues  as  to  how  to  work  out  this  problem .

Thanks  for  any  help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix is in the form of $A=vv^T+nuu^T-I$, where $v^T=(1,2,\ldots,n)$ and $u^T=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$. We can rewrite $v$ as the sum of two mutually orthogonal components $x=(v,u)u=\frac{(n+1)\sqrt{n}}{2}u$ and $y=v-(v,u)u=v-\frac{n+1}2(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$. Therefore $A$ is orthogonally similar to
$$
\pmatrix{\|x\|^2+n-1&\|x\|\|y\|\\ \|x\|\|y\|&\|y\|^2-1}\oplus (-I_{n-2})
$$
and hence
\begin{align*}
\det A
&=\left[(\|x\|^2+n-1)(\|y\|^2-1)-\|x\|^2\|y\|^2\right](-1)^{n-2}\\
&=(-1)^n\left[(n-1)(\|y\|^2-1)-\|x\|^2\right]\\
&=(-1)^n\left[(n-1)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\left(k-\frac{n+1}2\right)^2-1\right)
-\frac{n(n+1)^2}4\right]\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{12} (n^4 - 4n^3 - 7n^2 - 14n + 12).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The first $20$ determinants, calculated with PARI/GP

```
? for(n=1,20,a=matrix(n,n,x,y,0);for(i=1,n,for(j=1,n,if(i<>j,a[i,j]=i*j+1);if(i=
=j,a[i,j]=i*j)));print(n,"  ",matdet(a),"    ",factor(matdet(a))))
1  1    matrix(0,2)
2  -5    [-1, 1; 5, 1]
3  10    [2, 1; 5, 1]
4  -13    [-1, 1; 13, 1]
5  9    Mat([3, 2])
6  9    Mat([3, 2])
7  -50    [-1, 1; 2, 1; 5, 2]
8  125    Mat([5, 3])
9  -247    [-1, 1; 13, 1; 19, 1]
10  431    Mat([431, 1])
11  -694    [-1, 1; 2, 1; 347, 1]
12  1055    [5, 1; 211, 1]
13  -1535    [-1, 1; 5, 1; 307, 1]
14  2157    [3, 1; 719, 1]
15  -2946    [-1, 1; 2, 1; 3, 1; 491, 1]
16  3929    Mat([3929, 1])
17  -5135    [-1, 1; 5, 1; 13, 1; 79, 1]
18  6595    [5, 1; 1319, 1]
19  -8342    [-1, 1; 2, 1; 43, 1; 97, 1]
20  10411    [29, 1; 359, 1]
?
```

There does not seem to be any pattern. I added the factorizations, but I cannot notice any regularity. It is strange that the sign changes always with the exception $5->6$ upto $n=100$

Comment: Thanks  for  your  effort  to  help  but  what  I need  is  a  way  to  find  that  determinant  for  arbitrary  $n.$